# Remotely monitor top output on Linux from Windows

Tags: linux

I work on Windows 7 most of the time. I have a linux machine whose process I need to monitor from my Windows machine. Instead of ssh'ing into the linux machine and doing top, I want to install some application on my windows which would establish a connection to my linux machine and show me the memory usage of the processes in the application's GUI.
Is there a freeware like this ? I am pretty sure there is something out there that i can use.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Software recommendations are off-topic here (see [about]). That said, any application you install would still need to connect and authenticate to the remote sever so I don't see how it would be simpler than using ssh/top. The only alternative would be doing it over the web, can you create a file on the server that is accessible to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The metrics that you're describing can all be sent using SNMP so monitoring them remotely is not too much more than setting up a Cacti or Nagios instance (depending on your needs) and configure it to look to the specific SNMP events that you wish to monitor.

You can even host the cacti / nagios service on your linux host and then just access the web UI.

More info:

- Cacti: http://cacti.net/
- Nagios: http://www.nagios.org/